# S3 CRR for entire bucket except objects with certain prefix

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, database-replication

I am trying to set some replication rules for my S3 bucket in a way that it replicates all the objects in the bucket to another bucket in a different region, EXCEPT objects starting with a certain prefix (let's say test-prefix/). What would be the best way to set it up?

For example, let's say I have 2 rules such as:

- Rule 1: Configured to replicate entire bucket. STATUS is ENABLED with PRIORITY set as 1
- Rule 2: Configured to replicate objects with prefix (test-prefix/). STATUS is DISABLED with PRIORITY set as 2.

Will such a setup help me attain my objective to replicate the entire bucket apart from objects with certain prefix?

Comment: Can't you just around the logic? Replicate all the objects under a certain prefix?

Comment: @Mornor Well my bucket has tens of thousands of objects with different prefixes, it would be a pain to have to go through each and every prefix and create different replication rules for them.